# How do I disable auto-correct in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

How do I prevent Microsoft Edge from trying to auto-correct for  me?

I frequently have been using Edge as my client for https://www.irccloud.com/ and a couple other web-based chat services for chatting about various tech related subjects. 
Edge is really screwing me over when I type a command, function or something someone should use to do something it screws with case or changes the punctuation, or does other really annoying things.  I don't want any automatic 'corrections'.

A couple examples.

- If I type `ansible-cmdb` Edge is automatically changing this to `ansible-CMDB`.
- If I type 3 dots `...` it is getting changed to ellipsis character `…`.

I believe I have disabled everything under 'Windows Settings\Typing' except the highlight, and restarted Edge, and restarted the whole computer.  But Edge still seems to screw with things I type.  Which is really frustrating, when Edge I don't notice and Edge is resulting in me giving someone wrong information.

I would far much prefer that when I give people wrong information it be **my** fault because I am bad at crappy at typing or spelling over my computer screwing me over because it thinks it knows better then me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows 10 setting.  Go to Settings, Devices, Typing.  Change the settings there to match your needs.

Comment: I wish that worked, but as I mentioned I already have have disabled everything under Devices/Typing except 'highlight'.  I have restarted both Edge and the computer.